# What is "puck" in coffee brewing?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am reading the instructions of a trimming tool that came with my new espresso machine which say:

> The twist blade that trims down the **puck** to the right level to keep a consistent extraction.

This is not about ice hockey, so I have no idea what puck means here. I tried googling, to no avail.

Comment: The puck is the round thingy where you place the coffee:https://www.fivesenses.com.au/blog/do-you-know-your-puck/ And it does kind of look like hockey puck.

Comment: @Lambie - no, the round thingy where you place the coffee is the [portafilter basket](https://betterespressomachinesreviews.com/heck-portafilter-portafilter-facts-explained/). The **puck** is the round disk of coffee created when the coffee is compressed into the basket.

Comment: Ok, right. The puck is the the coffee, but it has the shape of a hockey puck.

Comment: Off-topic, but the relative fineness of the grind and the density of the compaction after tamping have a  far greater effect upon extraction than the absolute height of the coffee in the portafilter basket.  That twist blade is an odd feature.

Comment: And `puck espresso` yields umpteen results.  You're making me doubt your Google-fu, L. Moneta :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Particularly when put in an espresso machine, the coffee is ground very fine and compressed with a coffee tamper into a semi-solid mass that's the same basic shape and color as a hockey puck.  People who are really into espresso actually call this disc of coffee grounds a **puck**, especially after it has gotten wet and stuck together.

If you go to google and search for "coffee puck", you'll find thousands of baristas obsessing over various details of puck consistency and moisture levels, trying to correlate those attributes to the quality of the espresso shot that was produced.

Comment: [What does your coffee puck say about you?](https://www.baybeans.com.au/coffee-blog/what-does-your-coffee-puck-say-about-you)

Comment: Right, but I would not say it was the grounds, per se either. It's the shape of the coffee after it's tamped before the water goes through it.

Comment: @Lambie - It's called the puck because of the shape, but the usage of the word definitely applies to the disk of coffee grounds. In [this link](https://www.fivesenses.com.au/blog/do-you-know-your-puck/) that you posted in a previous comment, you'll find the phrase, "If your puck is too soft or muddy..."  That's definitely referring to the grounds itself since a shape can't be "muddy," but the grounds can be. And this is definitely referring to the grounds *after* the water goes through it.